# Search through server folders and display files that exist

Tags: php

I have a folder called uploads in this folder is a folder for the year the file was uploaded(2013,2014,2015 etc...), inside the year folder are usernames(rick, dan, edward etc...), inside the usernames folder are folders 1-12 for the month that the file was uploaded.

I want to search through the folders and if there is a file in the folder display the link, the problem I am having is figuring out how to do the check on all of the folders:

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

            //array for years to check for
            $year = array('2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020');
            $month = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12');

            //loop through years array and populate $existingYears[] array with years that exist on server
            foreach($year as $years){

                if(is_dir($yearPath = ABSPATH."/"."uploads/".$years."/".$username)){

                    $existingYears[] = $years;

                }

            }

            //loop through existings years
            foreach($existingYears as $year){

                //title
                print "<h1>".$year."</h1>";

                    //loop for months
                    for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {

                        if($i == 1){
                            $title = "January";
                        } elseif($i == 2){
                            $title = "February";
                        }elseif($i == 3){
                            $title = "March";
                        }elseif($i == 4){
                            $title = "April";
                        }elseif($i == 5){
                            $title = "May";
                        }elseif($i == 6){
                            $title = "June";
                        }elseif($i == 7){
                            $title = "July";
                        }elseif($i == 8){
                            $title = "August";
                        }elseif($i == 9){
                            $title = "September";
                        }elseif($i == 10){
                            $title = "October";
                        }elseif($i == 11){
                            $title = "November";
                        }elseif($i == 12){
                            $title = "December";
                        }

                        //path to months directories
                        $url=$userPath.'/'.$i;

                        $newUrl = $url.'/'.$files[2];

                        print $newUrl;

                        //check if directory exists
                        if(is_dir($url)){

                            //assign open state to $dir
                            $dir = opendir($url);

                            //add all files to $files[] array
                            while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){

                                $files[] = $file;

                            }
                            closedir($dir);

                            //display link to payslips
                            print "<div class='month-box' id='box$i'>";
                            print "<h2>".$title."</h2>";
                            print "<a class='download-link' id='download-link-$i' href='".$host."/uploads/".$year.'/'.$username.'/'.$i.'/'.$files[2]."'>Download</a>";
                            print "</div>";

                        }

                    }

            }

            ?>
```

Very messy I know, I am sure there is a better way to do this just not sure how.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I won't write code for you but point you in the right direction. Things to consider:
Based on your slashes, you seem to be running on a *nix based system so

1. Consider using unix `find` with php `shell_exec` ..
2. Try to apply filters (year,month etc) in the find call itself.
3. Instead of manually naming months, use php datetime class OR simply the date function

Comment: The application will need to work on all types of systems so don't want to restrain code to one system.

Comment: your "slashes" aren't windows compatible. You want to change that first.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a listing (in the form of an array) of all the files and directories:

```
$path = 'your/initial/path'
$start_dir = realpath($path);
$directory_arr = array();
$directories = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($start_dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$directories->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS); // skips dots '/.' and '/..'
foreach($directories as $directory => $directory) {
   $directory_arr[] = $directory;
}
```

This will give you a list of just the directories (swap code)

```
if(is_dir($directory)) {
    $directory_arr[] = $directory.'/';
}
```

This will give you a list of just the files (swap code)

```
if( ! is_dir($directory)) {
    $file_path_arr[] = $directory;
}
```